# How to access a DTO attribute when DTO is inside a hashmap in DOZER mapping file

Tags: dozer

I have a UserDTO which has userID field. The HashMap has this DTO as value for key User_Details.

I want to use DOZER mapping to set the userID attribute from **HashMap->User_Details->userId** to attribute **UserDisplayDTO->userId**.

How can I do this in Dozer XML mapping?

```
<mapping map-id="testMapping">
    <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
    <class-b>com.common.dto.UserDisplayDTO</class-b>
    <field>
        <a key="User_Details">this</a>
        <b>userId</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) for this. Atm, dozer xml mapping doesn't support a keybased hashmap lookup.

So for your case, you need something like

```
<field custom-converter="com.your.custom.converter.UserIdConverter">
    <a>hashmapfield</a>
    <b>userId</b>
</field>
```

In the UserIdConverter implementation, you would have to retrieve the value from the hashmap and return it (null checking etc. omitted for the sake of clarity):

```
@Override
public Long convertTo(HashMap map, Long userId) {
    UserDTO dto = (UserDTO)map.get("User_Details");
    return dto.getUserId();
}
```